# $\int_{C} z^{126}\cos^7(\pi z^{14}) + z|z| $ Over a specific contour .

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $C_1$ be the line segment connecting $i$ to $-i$ , and let $C_2$ be the semicircle connecting $-i$ to $i$.

(a) Give a parametrization of $C_1$ and of $C_2$

$C_1 :z=i-2i$t $t \in [0,1]$

$C_2 :z=e^{i t} $ $t \in [-\frac{\pi}{2} , \frac{\pi}{2}]$

(b)Let $f(z) = z^{126}\cos^7(\pi z^{14}) + z|z|$.Compte 
$$ \int_{C_1}f(z)\ dz \ \ \ ,\int_{C_2} f(z) \ dz \ \ \ , \int_{C_1 \cup C_2} f(z) \ dz $$

(c)Can you deduce that $f$ is not analytic in $D=\{z:|z|<2\}$

This is an Exam question It's supposed to be solved in at most 20 min.

What's the trick to calculate the integral in a quick way ?

Answer (score 1):

Put $g(z):=z^{126}\cos^7(\pi z^{14})$, $\ h(z):=z\>|z|$.

The integrals $\int_{C_i} g(z)\>dz$ are not elementary, but $\int_{C_1+C_2} g(z)\>dz=0$ since $g$ is an entire function.

The function $h$ is not analytic since $z\mapsto|z|$ isn't. The integrals can be computed as follows: Along $C_2$ one has $h(z)=z$. It follows that
$$\int_{C_2}h(z)\>dz=\int_{C_2} z\>dz={z^2\over2}\biggr|_{-i}^i=0\ .$$
Along the first half $C'$ of $C_1$ one has $|z|=-iz$, and along the second half $C''$ one has $|z|=iz$. It follows that
$$\int_{C_1} h(z)\>dz=-i \int_{C'}z^2\>dz+i\int_{C''}z^2\>dz=-i\>{z^3\over3}\biggr|_i^0+i\>{z^3\over3}\biggr|_0^{-i}=\ldots$$

Comment: Although in general the integral of $g$ is not elementary, is it not conceivable that we can spot that its value on this special range is $27$ or whatever? I certainly can't, and don't believe it has a simple answer, but ....

Comment: @ancientmathematician It has a simple answer .

Comment: Well tell us what the value of the integral is along $C_1$.

Comment: I used different parameterization $t \in [-1 ,1]$ so the integral is 0